# Can sets in redis be deterministic?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to get the best of both worlds. Using redis sets as well as having determinism. Is this possible?

I'm storing a set using the usual commands:

```
SADD myset "foo"
SADD myset "bar"
```

But then if I request an element to process

```
SRANDMEMBER myset
```

I'd like the element that is returned to be deterministic. I do not actually care which one it is, but I want the path in my code to be reproducible, or else debugging becomes considerably harder.

Is it possible to set the seed in redis, or use some other technique, to ensure that the three operations above, in sequence, will always return the same element?

Comment: You need this specific case to repeat a certain scenario in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - `SRANDMEMBER`'s behavior isn't controllable.

If you need order, even if for the sake of debugging only, I suggest you use a different approach. Sorted Sets are the natural candidate for this task and behave pretty much as Sets - use 0 score so the members are ordered lexicographically and replace the calls to `SRANDMEMBER` with `ZRANGE`, passing to it your own client-generated random rank or a deterministic one.